# Can I count number of return value format json in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

**Method in Controller**

```
public function getLike() {

   $this->Feed->UserLikeFeed->recursive = 1;
    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'contain' => array('UserLikeFeed','UserCommentFeed','UserShareFeed')
    );
    $like_comment_shares = $this->Paginator->paginate();
    $this->set(array(
        'like_comment_shares' => $like_comment_shares,
        '_serialize' => array('like_comment_shares')
    ));
}
```

**Model**

```
public $hasMany = array(

    'Image' => array(
        'className' => 'Image',
        'foreignKey' => 'feed_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'UserCommentFeed' => array(
        'className' => 'UserCommentFeed',
        'foreignKey' => 'feed_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
     'UserLikeFeed' => array(
        'className' => 'UserLikeFeed',
        'foreignKey' => 'feed_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
        'UserShareFeed' => array(
        'className' => 'UserShareFeed',
        'foreignKey' => 'feed_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
);
```

When I access the method in controller,it returns value like the image below. I want to get number of data. Ex: UserLikeFeed, it returns two value. I want to get 2. What should I do now? Thank you for helping.

**Result**

```
{
    "like_comment_shares": [

    {
        "Feed": {
            "id": "72",
            "admin_id": "2",
            "title": "New term",
            "description": "This is a new term"
        },
        "UserCommentFeed": [
            {
                "user_id": "1",
                "feed_id": "72",
                "created": null,
                "description": "Going home"
            },
            {
                "user_id": "1",
                "feed_id": "72",
                "created": null,
                "description": "Going School"
            }
        ],
        "UserLikeFeed": [
            {
                "user_id": "1",
                "feed_id": "72"
            },
            {
                "user_id": "2",
                "feed_id": "72"
            }
        ],
        "UserShareFeed": [

        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are paginating your data you will only get the values for that specific page based on your pagination limit, rather than thinking about counting the json results, simply count the results from the array before you serialize it to JSON, basically you can do something like:

```
 $userlikefeed_count = count($like_comment_shares['UserLikeFeed']);
```

Which will return the number of items in that array, you can then send this data to the controller as well:

```
$this->set(array(
    'like_comment_shares' => $like_comment_shares,
    'userlikefeed_count' => $userlikefeed_count
    '_serialize' => array('like_comment_shares', 'userlikefeed_count')
));
```

Comment: I am very thank you for your answer to help me. when I use $userlikefeed_count = count($like_comment_shares['UserLikeFeed']); It does not undefined index UserLikeFeed  . can you help me again?

Comment: try `count($like_comment_shares['Feed']['UserLikeFeed']);` It is hard to work out what model you are doing this from from your code!